# pasting an excel grid into an HTML form and pasting it back into an excel document

Tags: html, forms, user-experience

A friend of mine asked me about this 2 weeks ago and I am still trying to think about the best way to solve the problem.

Apparently the users ended up with a system where they get an excel file where they

1. have to manually fill up a column (I am expecting a lot of data).
2. the user would have to the grid into an html form
3. Have the pasted excel rows create rows in the DB

[image: Excel Form example]

Is there is a clean way to handle this problem? Should he write any client side to format the pasted text or should he handle it on the front end? I also worry about any mistakes made by the user pasting the wrong number of cells.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get rid of the Excel step, you could write a program that reads that Excel file and store the values in the DB.
I did some Excel processing with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) in Java.

Comment: That was a question that I asked him. The users are not uploading the full file for some reason. They are only pasting the part that is ready. It is an annoying limitation and IMO the whole process should be rewritten, but he will have to patch the problem for now.